# Javascript - Add data to the table from Api

Tags: javascript, api, datatables

I'm getting data from an Api with Javascript. I want to transfer the data to the table, but I couldn't.

I'm taking the data, but I don't know how to put it in the table.

My code

```
function tablo_getir() {
var dt = $('#base-style').DataTable();  
dt.clear().row();
    var apirun=getApi("/api/campaigns/");
     $.each(apirun, function(k, v) {
        dt.row.add(['<button class="btn btn-inverse" id="'+v.id+'" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#subeDetay" title="Detay"><i class="icofont icofont-eye-alt"></i></button>',
        v.id,
        v.name,               
        '<button class="btn btn-success" id="'+v.id+'" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#subeDuzenle" title="Düzenle"><i class="ti-pencil-alt"></i></button><button class="btn btn-danger" id="'+v.id+'" title="Sil"href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete"><i class="ti-trash"></i></button>']).draw(false);
        }); }
```

My getApi func:

```
function getApi (url,request) {
$('#alertSuccess').fadeOut('slow');
var response = "";
$.ajax({
        url: apiUrl+url+tokenim,
        type: 'get',
        async: false,
        headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        dataType: 'json',            
        success: function (data) {
                console.info(data);
                if(data.statusCode!=200) {
                        alert(data.message);
                        return false;
                } else {
                        response=data;
                }
        },
        error: function(data){
            $('#alertDanger').fadeIn('slow');
            $('#alertDanger .alert').text("Api çalışmasında hata oluştu");
            $('#alertDanger').fadeOut(5000);
        }
});
return response; }
```

Incoming data:
https://hizliresim.com/V90NlZ

I get an undefined error when the webpage is loaded. At the same time my data is not coming to the table.

Comment: what does your `getApi()` function return?

Comment: I can't figure that out from the link you provided. Could you share the `getApi()` functions code in your question?

Comment: Edited. Check it please. @AdamBaranyai

Answer (score 0):

Your most likely problem is, that you forgot to call DataTables `draw` method, after you added a row to the table. You can try modifying your code, like this:

```
dt.row.add(['<button class="btn btn-inverse" id="'+v.id+'" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#subeDetay" title="Detay"><i class="icofont icofont-eye-alt"></i></button>',
    v.id,
    v.name,               
    '<button class="btn btn-success" id="'+v.id+'" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#subeDuzenle" title="Düzenle"><i class="ti-pencil-alt"></i></button><button class="btn btn-danger" id="'+v.id+'" title="Sil"href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete"><i class="ti-trash"></i></button>']).draw(false);
    }).draw();
```

Here's a [link](https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html) on how to add new rows to `DataTable` tables.

Also, read about the `draw` function [here](https://datatables.net/reference/api/draw()). It has one input parameter, and depending on that, the table will be redrawn in different ways. Based on your question, I can't decide which parameter should you use for the `draw` table.

Comment: is your console returning any kind of error messages? if yes, what are those error messages?

Comment: Error message: an undefined alert

Comment: does the line where this error is thrown is related to any specific line from your code which you already shared with us? if yes, which one?